# PHP Error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
>
> Filename: controllers/user.php
>
> Line Number: 1

Backtrace:

```
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\user.php
Line: 1
Function: define

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Make sure user.php is User.php with codeigniter controllers and models etc have to have the first letter of class and file name upper case.

Comment: Add your code here, without how can we recognize what is the issue?

Comment: Also can you add the user.php controller code to your question by clicking on the edit button.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:

Comment: @DJSilver Please add the controller to your question by clicking on edit bit hard to guess

Answer (score 0):

This means you try to [define](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.define.php) a constant on that line. You must give it the name and the value, two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to post your code in the `controller/user.php` to track the exact issue, but form what i guess your first line in `user.php`  is something like this :

```
<?php if(!define('BASEPATH')) die("No direct Script Access allowed");
```

Change it to :

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) die("No direct Script Access allowed");
```